# How to compare two files with different filename in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

We have multiple files in a azure data lake gen2 folder, file name like
abc_test_20170505_120101.csv ,hash_abc_test_20170505_120101.csv
,abc_sample_20170505_110101.csv,
hash_abc_sample_20170505_110101.csv.

I want to copy abc_test_20170505_120101.csv with hash_abc_test_20170505_120101.csv

And
File abc_sample_20170505_110101.csv with hash_abc_sample_20170505_110101.csv

File abc_test file should be copy with hash_abc one and another file should be copy with hash one.

How we can do this using azure data factory.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by copy file with file? Do you want to union all rows from both files into a new file, or merge all columns into a new file? or just copy the files to another location?

Comment: Just want to copy the files to another location. Actually both files(abc_sample_20170505_110101.csv and hash_abc_sample_20170505_110101.csv) with hash and without hash fcontain same information about files like one files have data and another file have metadata so I want to match both files with name and filter out the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since there is a metadata file for every data file, you can use the following activities to get the an array of object with each object has keys called `data and metadata` with values as the respective filename.
- First I have used get metadata to get the list of files:

[image]

- Iterate through these child items. Inside for loop use an if activity to check whether the item's name starts with `hash` or not. We need names whose name does not start with hash. The following is the dynamic content I used as condition for if activity.

```
@not(startswith(item().name,'hash'))
```

[image]

- Inside the True path, use a set variable activity to build the object. The following is the dynamic content that I used:

```
{
    "data": "@{item().name}",
    "metadata":"@{concat('hash_',item().name)}"
}
```

- Now convert the above string variable to object using `json()` function and append it to an array using append variable activity.

[image]

- After executing the pipeline, you will get the results as shown in the below image:

[image]

- If there is no metadata file for any a particular data file, you can use additional conditions to check it after this process.